# Multiple inputs running in parallel in the same application vs. starting a new application for each input

Tags: drools, optaplanner

As i can see when running the application in debug mode there are 4 different threads on which Drools is running. When i start the application with two threads running two inputs in parallel again the same 4 threads remain (they don't turn to 8 for example).
My question is , is there a benefit from running the inputs in a separate application (and with this starting a separate Drools application) , or all of this is covered and we end up with the same results using one application and starting the inputs in parallel?

Comment: Can you input more per time by "running two inputs"? The issue is (as always) whether you are (initially) i/o bound or computational bound. Then it depends on the number of your cores. It may change from one Drools version to the next. And with the amount of processing the Engine needs to do, i.e., your rules. -- Benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages of using 1 JVM's:

- heap pooling
- JIT compilation only once in java code
- JIT compilation only once in DRL code iff you reuse your kiebases
- Ability to implement queueing and round-robin solving. See SolverManager issue and `runnablePartThreadLimit`'s purpose in Partitioned Search (which will also be supported on SolverManager at some point).

Advantages of using multiple JVM's:

- Garbage Collector works more efficiently usually
- Ability to link OS (especially on linux) process id's to specific cores. This allows to do round-robin solving through OS configuration.